# scanf() get junk values, no double issue

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having trouble with this little piece of code. The problem is related to the data entry. I can't get the data as they are typed. If I enter the following values:

> > g1 = 3; q = 3 and term(termo) = 3
> >       I get
> >     g1 = 3, q = 0 and term(termo) = 2686724.

Already tried using `getchar()` after `scanf,` and `fflush(stadin)` before and after data input routine, and also put space between `"% f (d)"`. Nothing works.
I am using DevC ++ and the CodeBlocks and both have the same problem (could be the gnu gcc?).

I don't know what else to do. Is the code, is the `scanf()` or is my PC that's in trouble?

This try to be a C code. The problem is in `termos_pg()` function routine. The sentence `printf("g1=%.f, q=%.f, termo=%d,\n",g1,q,termo);` into `calcula_pg()` function routine shows what I get into `termos_pg()` routine. Can anybody help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
float ind,gn,g1,val,q;
int termo,gx=0,i;
main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

char X;
printf ("\nSe houver parâmetro desconhecido, tecle s ou S, caso nao, ENTER.\n");
X=getch();
fflush(stdin);

if(X=='s' || X=='S'){
    es_pg();
    return (0);}
    else{
        termos_pg();
        return (0);
    }
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}

termos_pg()
{
printf("\nDigite o 1º termo da PG: ");
scanf("%f",&g1);

printf("Digite a razao da PG: ");
scanf("%f",&q);

printf("Digite a quantidade de termos: ");
scanf("%d",&termo);
calcula_pg(g1,q,termo);
}

calcula_pg(g1,q,termo)
{
printf("g1=%.f, q=%.f, termo=%d,\n",g1,q,termo);
printf("\n\tA sequência é: \n");
for(i=0;i<termo;i++)
    if(++gx==termo)
        printf("\ta%d= %20.f.\n",gx,(g1*powf(q,(termo-(termo-i)))));
    else
        printf("\ta%d= %20.f;\n",gx,(g1*powf(q,(termo-(termo-i)))));
        system("PAUSE");
}

es_pg(){;}
```

Comment: Note: Left code's `system("PAUSE");` original out-dented, though it should be indented to reflect it occurs after the `for()` loop and not only in the `else` clause.  Is that an issue?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given any types for your arguments to `calcula_pg`, which means that the compiler assumes you're passing `int`-typed variables, not `float`.

Here's an example program to demonstrate the effect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ints(int x, int y, int z)
{
    printf("ints: x == %.f, y == %.f, z == %d\n", x, y, z);
}

void floats(float x, float y, int z)
{
    printf("floats: x == %.f, y == %.f, z == %d\n", x, y, z);
}

int main()
{
    ints(3.14, 3.14, 5);
    floats(3.14, 3.14, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
ints: x == 0, y == 0, z == 3
floats: x == 3, y == 3, z == 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Add fflush(stdout) after every printf call before scanf

Comment: stdin and stdout are different, it doesnt help doing fflush(stdout) for scanf which is the same as fscanf(stdin, .. instead it is better to use fgets to read the line then sscanf to get the value.